# Testing all Letters?

Tags: python

I am working on a script and the script should read a text file and test to see if the specified letters(a,a,r,d,v,a,r,k) are on each line. Im having a problem as I am trying to check for 3 different a's instead of just one. My code is below:

```
#Variables
advk = ['a','a','r','d','v','a','r','k']
textfile = []
number = 0
life = 0

for line in open('input.txt', 'rU'):
    textfile.append(line.rstrip().lower())


while life == 0:
    if all(word in textfile[number] for word in advk):
        printed = number + 1
        print ("Aardvark on line " + str(printed))
        number+=1
        if number == len(textfile):
            life+=1

    else:
        number+=1
```

Comment: So when one of the letters in `advk` is found on the line, you want that letter to be "consumed" and not count for the rest of the search?

Comment: for clarrification, you are looking that a "line" of text in a file contains the letters `['a','a','r','d','v','a','r','k']` in that order? or that they are contained on the line at all? in which case you can check unique values, `['a','r','d','v','k']`. or do you simply want to find out if the word "aardvark" exists in a line of a file?

Comment: @InbarRose I want to see if I can make aardvark out of characters on that line.

Comment: @DraganMarjanovic do the letters need to be in the correct order? or just present in the correct quantity?

Comment: @InbarRose just present in the correct quantity =D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everytime you want to count something in python, keep the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class in mind.

---

```
from collections import Counter

advk = Counter(['a','a','r','d','v','a','r','k'])

with open('input.txt', 'rU') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        if not advk - Counter(line.lower()):
            print ("Aardvark on line " + str(i+1))
```

---

Given the input line

> dffdaardvarksdsda

the Counter would look like these

```
Counter({'d': 5, 'a': 4, 'f': 2, 's': 2, 'r': 2, 'k': 1, 'v': 1})
```

and

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'r': 2, 'd': 1, 'k': 1, 'v': 1})
```

for your list of letters to search.

We use a trick by simply substracting the two Counters `advl - Counter(line.lower())` and check if the resulting Counter has no elements left.

---

Other things to note:

You can use the [with](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement to ensure your file gets closed.
You can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead counting the line numbers.

Comment: Thanks Man really helps been messing around with this for around 4 hours now hahaha.

Comment: +1 for bringing my attention to a standard library class I have never noticed, but often have use for. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

if advk list is variable and contents are read from somewhere else then to maintain unique elements in the list you can convert it to set and check.

```
advk = ['a','a','r','d','v','a','r','k']
advk = list(set(advk))
```

This makes advk a unique list and avoids check multiple 'a's in the line.

Comment: Two things: why convert it back to a list? Sets are iterable, and the point of a set is checking for membership quickly (you lose the fast hash-based membership test when you convert back to a list). Also, it seems like Dragan wants the whole word "aardvark" to be scrambled on the line. This approach would let "ardvrk" through.

Comment: And stylistically, since strings are iterable, you might as well just say `advk = set("aardvark")`.

Answer (score -3):

```
# If the line "ardvrk" should match, this is a solution:
chars=set('aardvark')
for nr, line in enumerate(open('input.txt', 'rU')):
    if not chars-set(line): # is subset?
        print 'match', nr, line,
```

Comment: plus one, not sure if he wants to check for upper case matches or not though.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, ardvrk should *not* match, so this isn't a solution to the OP's question.

Comment: also check line.count("a") >= 3

Comment: When I wrote this answer, it was not clear for me if the line needs to contain 3 times "a". The comment in the code tells this. But if some one has fun in down voting, do it.